# Accessing Current Page's Frontmatter -- Gatsby/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Is it possible to access the current page's frontmatter through the default layout.

Using graphql, is there an option to filter a query based on the page's url?

**.MDX Frontmatter**

```
---
Title: 'About Us'
---
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
    options: {
        defaultLayouts: {
            pages: require.resolve('./src/layouts/default.js'),
        },
    },
}
```

**default.js**

```
<>
    <header>?? Insert MDX Title ??</header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are generating pages from `./src/pages/` automatically using a default MDX template you still need to add the following to your `plugins` section in `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `pages`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
  }
}
```

Now you can access the frontmatter with `pageContext.frontmatter` as mentioned in the documentation i.e.:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from './layout'

export default ({ children, pageContext }) => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{pageContext.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <article>{children}</article>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. One way to step through it is to run `gatsby develop` and run your queries against the GraphiQL instance that gets ran. I have the title in my .mdx files and it is available through the `allMdx` and `mdx` schema. The Gatsby documentation [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/programmatically-creating-pages/#make-a-template-for-your-posts) explains how to set up your component with the query.

```
{
  allMdx {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
  mdx {
    frontmatter {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The pages are not programmatically displayed. I need the layout to dynamically pull the frontmatter title from the page which is calling it. If layout were called by the page, I would use props; however, I'm using a default layout via the mdx plugin.

Comment: You'll still need a query or access it through the props to pull in the data, even if you're not programatically creating the pages. This document may be more fitting to what you are trying to use. [Using Frontmatter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/writing-pages/#using-frontmatter-in-mdx)

Answer (score 0):

MDX frontmatter is passed automatically along with `children` into the parent context.

`{props.pageContext.frontmatter.Title}`