# How to fetch front-matters of asciidoc in Gatsby using gatsby-transformer-asciidoc

Tags: reactjs, documentation, asciidoc, asciidoctor, gatsby-plugin

I'm building a documentation website using Gatsby. Doc contents are asciidoc.
So I'm using gatsby-transformer-asciidoc to fetch all .adoc files.
The problem is there is some metadata placed in docs front-matter like this:

```
---
title: Title
versions: 1,2,3,4,5
---
```

and I need to fetch this metadata.
I tried all available plugins for gatsby but they didn't help. so I will appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123284/accessing-current-pages-frontmatter-gatsby-react
It doesn't appear to care what source the frontmatter is contained within.

Comment: gatsby-transformer-asciidoc doesn't accept frontmatters in graphQl query and results in undefiend.

Comment: Ok. I'm not a Gatsby user, but this certainly isn't an Asciidoc problem. I hope someone else can help you!